# Replacing Old Value with new value based on userform input

Tags: vba, userform

I currently am experiencing a run-time error'91' Object Variable or With Block Variable not set for the highlighted code. The objective of that code is to search for a named product based on the input from the user form then offset it to the quantity available. Afterwards, it will replace the old value with a new value by subtracting the current value with the ordered quantity.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Order_Click()
Dim X As Integer
Dim nextrow As Range
Dim DateCus As Range
Dim i As Range

If Me.txtOrder_No.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Add an Order No"
Exit Sub
End If

If Me.Order1.Value = "" And Me.Qty1.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "No order was specified. Please input an order"
Exit Sub
Else
For X = 1 To 8

Set nextrow = Sheet6.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
If Me.Controls("Order" & X).Value > "" And Me.Controls("Qty" & X).Value > "" Then

If Me.Controls("Qty" & X).Value < Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.Controls("Order" & X), Sheet4.Range("Products"), 4, 0) Or Me.Controls("Qty" & X).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.Controls("Order" & X), Sheet4.Range("Products"), 4, 0) Then

'This is the one causing the error
Set i = Sheet3.Range("Ingredients").Find(Me.Controls("Order" & X).Value).Offset(0, 3)

i = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.Controls("Order" & X), Sheet4.Range("Products"), 4, 0).Value - Me.Controls("Qty" & X).Value



'End If

Else
MsgBox "There's no stock available for one of the orders"
```

Comment: Always helps to note which line is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

try substituting

```
Set nextrow = Sheet6.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

with

```
Set nextrow = Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

and the likes ("Sheet3", "Sheet4",...), too.